# perform modal segue, not using storyboard

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to perform a `Modal Segue` like action, **not** using Storyboard?

In other words, I just need to show another View with an animation like Modal Segues but since I need my app to be compatible with older iOS versions, I'm not able to use Storyboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just found it.

It's possible with:

```
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: for those coming to this late, the above method is now deprecated and replaced by UIViewController method: presentViewController:animated:completion: